# Pycharm manage.py custom commands

Tags: django, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm 2.7.2, which is the latest version to date.

In my settings file for a django project, I used the following lines to configure my `INSTALLED_APPS` setting variable.

```
DJANGO_APPS = (
    ....
)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    'south',
)

LOCAL_APPS = (
    'blog',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PART_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
```

Now, south's features do not show up on `manage.py`. How do I run a custom `manage.py` command to get things working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm doesn't understand concatenation for `INSTALLED_APPS`, there is an issue logged about it:

- [PY-8413](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8413) PyCharm settings.py parser should understand concatenation in INSTALLED_APPS initialization

Comment: May I ask, is there a good guide on how to integrate Heroku with PyCharm? I am having trouble with the independently created add-on, `Heroku Integration`.

Comment: You should contact Heroku integration plug-in vendor for help.

Comment: Is Jetbrains going to make a heroku integration, i.e. made by the pycharm team?

Comment: It's not in the roadmap yet, related issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-9040.

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm itself supports running `south` management commands. See [relevant issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-2859).

Looks like pycharm doesn't understand the structure of your project. Recheck if you configured it correctly.